# Cannot create a for loop to find element of an array in 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

So I have an array (of 9 elements) in ascending order and in another function I have a 3x3 matrix (same elements but unordered) and I want **to find row and column of each element of the array in the matrix**, but I cannot write it properly:

```
int find_path(int matrix_1[3][3], int array_1[9], int n) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            if (i == 9) {
                break;
            }
            if (matrix_1[j][k] == array_1[i]) {
                printf("(%d, %d)", j, k);
                j = 0;
                k = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say " i have a 3x3 matrix", so what is the meaning of `int matrix_1[][100]`? I'd have expected `int matrix_1[3][3]`. Please make a [mre] to demonstrate how you call the function (the first parameter is especailly interesting) and how it fails. Also, please try what I expected. Maybe it solves already.

Comment: @Ahmad Labouff Why is the return type of the function int? What does the function return?

Comment: @Ahmad Labouff Can it be that the matrix does not contain an element from the array?

Comment: `matrix_1[j][k] = array_1[i]` I'm sure you mean `==` instead

Comment: I am with @SaymoinSam. Try their proposal in combination with mine. Either of the two problems can break your function.

Comment: @SaymoinSam yes I did forget it, thanks. but it still doesn't work

Comment: can you tell us what you want to return from find_path function

Comment: My main goal is to for each element of array find it's row and column in the matrix. The elements are the same but the order is different

Comment: So basically you array and you matrix have the same elements, ok and you loop over the matrix and "find the row and column of each element of the array in the matrix" then what do you do with each row and col? just print them?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to just print the row and col of each matched element in the matrix with your array, it can be done like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void find_path(int matrix_1[][3], int array_1[]) {
  for(int i = 0;i < 9; i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j < 9; j++) {
      if(matrix_1[i / 3][i % 3] == array_1[j]) {
        printf("The item '%i' matrix[%i][%i] is the same item array[%i]\n", array_1[j], i / 3, i % 3, j);
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int matrix[][3] = {
    {1, 6, 8}, {3, 9, 2}, {7, 4, 5}
  }, array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

  find_path(matrix, array);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
The item '1' matrix[0][0] is the same item array[0]
The item '6' matrix[0][1] is the same item array[5]
The item '8' matrix[0][2] is the same item array[7]
The item '3' matrix[1][0] is the same item array[2]
The item '9' matrix[1][1] is the same item array[8]
The item '2' matrix[1][2] is the same item array[1]
The item '7' matrix[2][0] is the same item array[6]
The item '4' matrix[2][1] is the same item array[3]
The item '5' matrix[2][2] is the same item array[4]
```

Comment: Why do you assume there should be a relationship between positions in the matrix and positions in the array?

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes
because Op said so "I have an array (of 9 elements) in ascending order and in another function I have a 3x3 matrix (same elements but unordered)"

Comment: OK, I had not noticed the outer loop running from `0` to `9`.  You solution works but is a little bit obscure, you might change the outer loop as `for (int i = 0; i < 3 * 3; i++)` to underscore the fact that it enumerates the matrix cells. Using 2 nested loops is more readable and avoids unnecessary divisions and modulo operations, which the compiler might or might not optimize out.

Comment: From the OP's code, I think the output should be in the order of the array, hence you should transpose the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not change the function declaration every five minutes.

Your function has the return type `int` but returns nothing. It should have the return type `void`.

The function can look the following way

```
void find_path( int matrix_1[][3], int array_1[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n * n; i++ )
    {
        int found = 0;

        size_t row = 0, col = 0;

        while ( !found && row < n )
        {
            while ( !found && col < n )
            {
                if ( !( found = matrix_1[row][col] == array_1[i] ) )
                {
                    ++col;
                }    
            }

            if ( !found ) ++row;
        }

        printf( "(%zu, %zu)", row, col );
    }
}
```

If the arrays were initially declared as having sizes equal to 100 then just change the function declaration like

```
void find_path( int matrix_1[][100], int array_1[], size_t n )
```

In the both cases the value of the parameter n shall be equal to 3 when the function is called if you was used this value to fill the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Your function will not make a thorough test because you reset `j` and `k` to `0` inside the inner loop, but since `k` is incremented before the next iteration, `matrix[0][0]` will not be compared to the next element of the array, hence the output will be incomplete if `matrix[0][0]` is not the smallest element in the matrix.

Note also the `n` is unused and it is unclear what this argument is supposed to be. Furthermore the function is defined as returning an `int` but does not return anything.

It is confusing and error prone to change the loop index variables inside the body of the loop. You can simply write 3 nested loops: for the matrix cells to be enumerated in the order of appearance in the array, you can iterate the outer loop for the array elements and iterate on the matrix rows and columns in the inner loops:

```c
void find_path(int matrix_1[3][3], int array_1[9], int n) {
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                if (matrix_1[j][k] == array_1[i]) {
                    printf("(%d, %d)", j, k);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (k < 3)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will output the same matrix cell for duplicate values. If there are no duplicate values, the `break` statements and the second `if` statement can be removed.

Here is a simple fix on your code:

```c
int find_path(int matrix_1[3][3], int array_1[9], int n) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            if (matrix_1[j][k] == array_1[i]) {
                printf("(%d, %d)", j, k);
                if (++i == 9)
                    return i;
                j = 0;
                k = -1; // restart the inner loop at 0,0
            }
        }
    }
    return i; // return the number of values found.
}
```